# How to replace text / string in a file with robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have copied a file in my current working directory. This file has a text:

> order value=78

I want to replace this text with new one

> parcel value= 500

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Using `Get File` from OperatingSystem Library you can read the contents of the file,
and using `Replace String` from String Library you can replace the string and 
using `Create File` from OperatingSystem library you can create the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the file, in which you want to make replacement, is large AND you don't want to load the whole file contents in a variable, then you can make use of `Run` keyword from OperatingSystem Library. The keyword will execute the shell command, here it is "sed" and make the replacement.
(Of course, you should be on Linux in this case)

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of replacing the text in a file
| | ${result}= | Run | sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' myfile.txt
```

The variable `result` will hold the stdout which you get after running the shell command.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a python script for this. Put the code below in a .py file and load this in your robot file using Library in the settings part.
Next in the robot file use this keyword as:

Replace line in file | file | searchExp1 | replaceLine

```
def Replace_line_in_file(file,searchExp1,replaceLine):
    """ Open a file (like input.txt) and find the line that
        contains the string searchExp1.
        and replace that complete line by replaceLine.
        When there are multiple lines that contain searchExp1
        then all those lines will be replaced
    """
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp1 in line:
            line = replaceLine+'\n'
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the above keyword "Replace line in file".
 But I get the error: Exception TypeError: TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable",) in > ignored

What other changes are required.

Comment: This would be more suitable as a comment - not an answer, as it does not answer the question.